# Method of solving an Associated Legendre Equation with m=0, and m not equal to 0 with explanation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, legendre-polynomials, legendre-symbol, frobenius-method

I am looking to find the Legendre polynomial for the following standard Associated Legendre equation:

$$\left(\frac{d}{dx}[1-x^2]\frac{d}{dx}+\lambda-\frac{m^2}{1-x^2}\right)\Theta(x)=0$$

I have found the indicial equation for m=0, but not for m$\neq$0. How do I go about solving this case?

Answer (score 1):

What you can show is that, if $y$ is a solution of
$$
             \frac{d}{dx}\left((1-x^2)\frac{dy}{dx}\right)+\mu y =0,
$$
then
$$
       w=(1-x^2)^{m/2}\frac{d^my}{dx^m}
$$
is a solution of
$$
       \frac{d}{dx}\left((1-x^2)\frac{dy}{dx}\right)-\frac{m^2}{1-x^2}y+\mu y = 0. \tag{$\dagger$}
$$
Therefore, if $P_n(x)$ is the Ordinary Legendre Polynomial, which is the polynomial solution of $((1-x^2)y')'+n(n+1)y=0$, then
$$
        P_{n,m}(x) = (1-x^2)^{m/2}\frac{d^{m}}{dx^{m}}P_{n}(x)
$$
is a solution of the Associated Legendre Equation $(\dagger)$. This holds for a fixed $m$ and for all $n \ge m$ (for $m > n$, the above is identically $0$.) So the Associated Legendre equation has eigenvalues
$$
            \mu_n=n(n+1),\;\;\; n=m,m+1,m+2,\cdots.
$$
**For example**: $x$ is a solution of the ordinary equation with $\mu=(1)(1+1)=2$. Therefore
$$
                \sqrt{1-x^2}\frac{d}{dx}x = \sqrt{1-x^2}
$$
is a solution of the associated equation with $\mu=(2)(1)$. To check this,
$$
       \frac{d}{dx}\left((1-x^2)\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)-\frac{1}{1-x^2}\sqrt{1-x^2} \\
   = -\frac{d}{dx}\left((1-x^2)\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)-\frac{1^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \\
   = -\frac{d}{dx}(x\sqrt{1-x^2})-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \\
   = -\sqrt{1-x^2}+x\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \\
   = -\sqrt{1-x^2}+\frac{x^2-1+1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \\
   = -2\sqrt{1-x^2}
$$
Therefore, as expected, $f=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ is a solution of
$$
        \frac{d}{dx}\left((1-x^2)\frac{df}{dx}\right)-\frac{1^2}{1-x^2}f+(2)(1)f=0.
$$
**Using the Method of Frobenius:** Start by rewriting the equation as
$$
     \frac{d^2f}{dx^2}-\frac{2x}{1-x^2}\frac{df}{dx}-\frac{m^2}{(1-x^2)^2}f+\frac{\lambda}{1-x^2}f = 0.
$$
In order to consider the equation at the singular point $x=-1$, which is a regular singular point, you have to expand in powers of $(x+1)$. For $x=-1$, you only need the coefficients $A$, $B$, $C$ shown below
$$
     \frac{d^2f}{dx^2}+\left[\frac{A}{x+1}+\cdots\right]\frac{df}{dx}+\left[\frac{B}{(x+1)^2}+\cdots\right]f=0.
$$
You can easily determine $A$ and $B$. For example,
$$
      -\frac{2x}{1-x^2}=\frac{1}{x+1}\left[\frac{2x}{x-1}\right]
     \implies A = \left.\frac{2x}{x-1}\right|_{x=-1} = 1. \\
      -\frac{m^2}{(1-x^2)^2}=\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}\left[-\frac{m^2}{(x-1)^2}\right]
   \implies B=-\left.\frac{m^2}{(x-1)^2}\right|_{x=-1}=-\frac{m^2}{4}.
$$
So the indicial equation comes from solving Euler's equation
$$
       (x+1)^2f''+A(x+1)f'+Bf = 0,\;\;\; f=(x+1)^r \\
        r(r-1)+Ar+B=0 \\
         r^2-r+r-\frac{m^2}{4}=0 \\
         r^2=\frac{m^2}{2^2} \\
         r = \pm \frac{m}{2}.
$$
Only the root with the largest real part--in this case $\frac{m}{2}$--is guaranteed to give a solution $(x+1)^{m/2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(x+1)^n$. If you want to take out the singularity at both endpoints $x=\pm 1$, then you can substitute $y=(1-x^2)^{m/2}w$ into the original equation and then solve by a series. In other words, the method of Frobenius leads to the same place in terms of the substitution.

Comment: I see, this does look really good. Something I forgot to specify though- we need to use the method of Frobenius instead. I have solved the m=0 case, but I am still struggling with the m is not equal to 0 case. Do you know anything further regarding this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @manuking : The method of Frobenius works out the same way, provided you factor out the required factor at both endpoints. But you can work at one endpoint at a time if you want.

Comment: @manuking : I've added more for you concerning the method of Frobenius.

Comment: Thanks for that mate. But it seems that you have lost the lambda along the way? lambda=l(l+1), of course. Any chance you could explain why it's gone please? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ignore that^ I've found out why. I have gone the long way around and come to the same roots as you with the full method of Frobenius expanded- I'm confused on how to implement the next step though. I have been asked to find the first few terms of this series to be specific- do you know how to do this? Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: @manuking : The indicial equation gives you a substitution. If $r$ is the root with the largest real part at $x=1$, for example, then you know there is a solution $(1-x)^r \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k (x-1)^k$. Either plug the series $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k(1-x)^{k+r}$ directly into the equation, or make the substitution $y(x)=(1-x)^{r}w(x)$, knowing that $w$ will have a McClaurin series. This equation is unusual in that you have symmetry about $x=0$.  That allows you solve in powers of $x$ instead of $(x-1)$ and $(x+1)$ by making the substation $y(x)=(1-x^2)^rw(x)$. Frobenius solves at $x=\pm 1$.