# Associated Legendre Polynomials from the Schrodinger Equation for the Hydrogen Atom

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, divergent-series, quantum-mechanics

EDIT: See below for answer, I found an alternative approach which is better in my opinion than trying to find a power series solution. I still don't fully understand why $m>l$ i.e. $P_l^m=0$ is not an acceptable solution. Intuitively I guess this results in the wave function being equal to zero and maybe we have to be able to normalise the wave function.

How can I study the convergence of the following series:

$$ P_l^m=(1-x^2)^{m/2}[c_0+c_1x+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}c_kx^k]$$

where $$c_{k+2}=\frac{((m+k+1)(m+k)-A)}{(k+2)(k+1)} c_k$$

In particular, how is it possible to show that the series only converges for $A=l(l+1)$ where $l$ is a nonnegative integer, $-l\leqslant m\leqslant l$?

This series which comes up when solving the Schrodinger equation for the hydrogen atom represents an associated Legendre polynomial (according to [this page](https://users.aber.ac.uk/ruw/teach/327/hatom.php)).

Note that it is possible to show the series is equivalent to the following;

$$P_l^m= (1-x^2)^{m/2}[c_0 + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} c_0x^{2k}\prod_{i=1}^{k}\frac{(m+2i-1)(m+2i-2)-A}{2i(2i-1)}] + (1-x^2)^{m/2}[c_1x + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}c_1x^{2k+1}\prod_{j=1}^{\lfloor{(2k+1)/2}\rfloor}\frac{(m+2j)(m+2j-1)-A}{2j(2j+1)}]$$

which is equivalent to;

$$(1-x^2)^{m/2}(c_0\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{c_{2k}}{c_0}x^{2k}+c_1\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{c_{2k+1}}{c_1}x^{2k+1})$$

Alternatively rather than examining the convergence of the series it might be easier to show that the series is equivalent to the following definition of Legendre polynomials:

$$P_l^m = (-1)^m(1-x^2)^{m/2}\frac{d^m}{dx^m}P_l(x)$$

where

$$P_l(x)=\frac{1}{2^l l!}\frac{d^l}{dx^l}[(x^2-1)^l]$$

Instead of proving the values of $l$ and $m$ for which the series converges it might be easier to show that it is equivalent to this definition from which it is quite intuitive that $l$ is a nonnegative integer since it is the order of a derivative and for the same reason $m$ must be an integer. Taking a derivative of order $l+m$ in the definition of $P_{l,m}$ implies that $-l$ is a lower bound on $m$. If $m>l$ then $P_{l,m}=0$ although I'm not sure why this is not possible.

In order to solve the polar differential equation I made the substitution $y(x)=(1-x^2)^{m/2}f(x)$ which gives another differential equation in terms of f(x) which can be solved this using a power series giving the result above.

Notice that;

$$c_k = \frac{((m+k-1)(m+k-2)-A)}{k(k-1)} c_{k-2}, k=2,3,4,5,...$$

It's possible to get a product formula rather than a recursive formula for the coefficients.

$$c_k= c_0\prod_{i=1}^{k/2}\frac{(m+2i-1)(m+2i-2)-A}{2i(2i-1)}, \quad  \text{k even}$$

$$c_k= c_1\prod_{i=1}^{\lfloor{k/2}\rfloor}\frac{(m+2i)(m+2i-1)-A}{2i(2i+1)}, \quad \text{k odd}$$

then a series of all the even terms is $c_0 + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} c_{2k}x^{2k}$ and a series with all the odd terms is $c_1x + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} c_{2k+1} x^{2k+1}$ where we use the appropriate even/odd formula for $c_{2k}$ and $c_{2k+1}$.

There is some discussion [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/582787/what-is-the-general-solution-of-the-associated-legendre-differential-equation-wh) although I didn't find it very helpful, if someone can provide a more in depth explanation that would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Crossposted to https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/606137/2451

Comment: This might be relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2069695/method-of-solving-an-associated-legendre-equation-with-m-0-and-m-not-equal-to-0?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

I found a better approach as described [here](https://www.reed.edu/physics/courses/P342.S10/Physics342/page1/files/Lecture.22.pdf).

When solving the polar equation you get an equation $$(1-x^2)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-2x\frac{dy}{dx}+(l(l+1)-\frac{m^2}{1-x^2})y=0$$

If you make the substitution $y=(1-x^2)^{m/2}f(x)$ you get a new differential equation;

$$(1-x^2)\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}-2x(m+1)\frac{df}{dx}+(l(l+1)-m(m+1))f(x)=0$$

If you set $m=0$ you get the regular Legendre equation for which the ordinary Legendre polynomial $P_l$ is a solution. If you differentiate the equation above you get again the regular Legendre equation except $f$ is replaced by $f'$ and $m$ is replaced by $m+1$ that means that since $P_l$ solves the equation for m=0, $P_l'$ solves the equation for m=1. You can continue differentiating and the same holds for a given m the solution of the above equation is the mth derivative of the Legendre polynomial. You could prove that it holds for all $m$ by induction. Then since we made a substitution $y=(1-x^2)^{m/2}f(x)$ the solution to the original equation is $$P_l^m=(1-x^2)^{m/2}\frac{d^m}{dx^m}P_l$$ which is called an associated Legendre polynomial. You can deduce from the azimuth equation that $m$ must be an integer as described [here](https://users.aber.ac.uk/ruw/teach/327/hatom.php), I found this easiest if you express the solution to the azimuth equation in terms of sines and cosines rather than exponentials.

If you set $m=0$ you get that the solution is the Legendre polynomial $P_l$ which involves a derivative of order $l$ therefore $l$ must be a nonnegative integer since it is the order of a derivative. Then if you expand the definition of the associated Legendre polynomial you have a derivative of order $l+m$ which means that $m$ must be bounded below by $-l$. We have deduced that $l$ is a nonnegative integer and that $m$ is an integer bounded below by $-l$.

How can we deduce that $m\le l$? If $m>l$ then $P_l^m=0$. Maybe this is not allowed because we have to be able to normalise the wave function. Is this an allowable solution?